# `std::terminate` invocation in a `noexcept` function with limited visibility - gcc vs clang codegen

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, code-generation, noexcept

Consider the following code snippet:

```
void f();

void a()          { f(); }
void b() noexcept { f(); }
```

In the scenario above, the body of `f` is not visible to the compiler in the current translation unit. Therefore, since `b` is marked `noexcept`, additional code must be generated on the caller side to make sure that the exception is caught and `std::terminate` is invoked.

That's what `clang++ -Ofast -std=c++2a` does *(trunk version)*:

```
a(): # @a()
  jmp f() # TAILCALL
b(): # @b()
  push rax
  call f()
  pop rax
  ret
  mov rdi, rax
  call __clang_call_terminate
__clang_call_terminate: # @__clang_call_terminate
  push rax
  call __cxa_begin_catch
  call std::terminate()
```

However, `g++ -Ofast -std=c++2a` does not *(trunk version)*:

```
a():
  jmp f()
b():
  jmp f()
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/GkDx8g)

---

How does `g++` get away with this? Shouldn't code be generated on the caller side as the body of `f` is not visible?

...or is this just a weird Compiler Explorer quirk?

Comment: Afaik gcc just handles exceptions differently using eh personality function. Godbolt just strip it. This [discussion](http://llvm.1065342.n5.nabble.com/Re-cfe-dev-Code-generation-for-noexcept-functions-td68484.html) seems related.

Comment: This question may be more on-point if `-O3` is used, as `-Ofast` disregards standards compliance.

Comment: @DanM. That's true, and one can see that in Godbolt output, too, one only needs to turn on '.text'. However, it's unclear, how EH personality function can diagnose whether the current instance of `f()` was called from `b()`. After jump instruction is executed, there will be no evidence on the stack that it was from there.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ach answered, there is a [bug opened on gcc bug tracker](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/). But if I may say so, it is not a major issue.

The impact is that an exception will leak instead of terminating the program but:

- if you want to call terminate on uncaught exception, that's already the case
- if you want no-throw exception safety guarantee, that doesn't provide it.

The only case I can think of is during development. Or in environments were it is mandatory to fail if a contract is broken (when life is at stake) ; in this case, compilers and the feature to use are tightly controlled.

Andrzej is making a good case in [his article - noexcept — what for ?](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/)